# Awaiting response from server in setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have a chatbot, which i want to implement using ReactJS.

I have a state like this:

```
 state={
    currentMessage: {
        content: '',
        user: '', 
    },
    messages: []
}
```

the idea is that the user can add messages to the `messages[]` in the state, and the response from the server will also be added.

So far i have this

```
 addMessageHandler = () =>{
    const message = this.state.currentMessage
    console.log(message.content.length)
    if(message.content.length > 5 && whiteSpaceValidation(message.content)){
        this.setState(prevState =>({
            messages: [...this.state.messages, this.state.currentMessage],
            }), () => this.getResponseHandler()
        )
    }
}

getResponseHandler = () =>{
    console.log('in handler', )
    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/chatbot',  {message: this.state.currentMessage.content})
    .then(res => this.setState(prevState =>({
        messsages: [...this.state.messages, res.data],
        currentMessage: {
                content: '',
                user: ''
            }, 
            loading: false
    }),  () => console.log(res.data)))
}
```

the userinputtet message get put into the array correctly, but in my callback function from my first `setState`, the response from the server is not placed correctly into the messages array.

I have tried with some dummy vraibles which gets executed fine but i can't seem to get the server reponse into the array

when i log the `res.data` it succesfully outputs a javascript object

EDIT:

i have tried a diferent implementation with sockets previously, which might work better? 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second `setState()`, your `messages` attribute has 3 `s`.

Comment: Your welcome, please validate the answer if it solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

If your setState depends on the old state, like your current case, always use prevState instead of this.state. React will make sure that no conflict happens.

```
 addMessageHandler = () =>{
    const message = this.state.currentMessage
    console.log(message.content.length)
    if(message.content.length > 5 && whiteSpaceValidation(message.content)){
        this.setState(prevState =>({

            // use prevState instead of this.state
            messages: [...prevState.messages, prevState.currentMessage],
            }), () => this.getResponseHandler()
        )
    }
}

getResponseHandler = () =>{
    console.log('in handler', )
    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/chatbot',  {message: this.state.currentMessage.content})
    .then(res => this.setState(prevState =>({

        // use prevState instead of this.state
        messages: [...prevState.messages, res.data],
        currentMessage: {
                content: '',
                user: ''
            }, 
            loading: false
    }),  () => console.log(res.data)))
}
```